# Мажорирование и расшифровка ошибочного сообщения

Tags: c#

Задача выглядит так:

> Пусть по некоторому каналу связи передается сообщение, имеющее вид последовательности нулей и единиц (или точек и тире). Из-за помех возможен ошибочный прием некоторых сигналов: нуль может быть воспринят как единица и наоборот. Для повышения надежности передачи сообщений применяют мажорирование, когда каждый сигнал троируется (например 101 преобразуется в 111000111). При расшифровке три последовательные цифры заменяются той цифрой, которая среди этой тройки встречается по крайней мере дважды. Написать программу шифровки и расшифровки мажорированных сообщений.

Получилось сделать троение чисел, не могу сделать алгоритм выбора двух чисел из 3. 
Возьмем к примеру 101 110 011 (Без пробелов). Помогите получить 1 1 1 (Без пробелов). Хочу получить универсальный алгоритм, чтобы можно было любые растроенные числа написать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, можно просто пройтись по строке и посчитать, что нужно

```
public string Major(string input)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length / 3);   

    for(int i=0; i<input.Length; i+=3)
    {       
        var ones = 0;
        var zeroes = 0;
        for(int j=i; j<input.Length && j<i+3; j++)
        {
            if (input[j] == '1') ones++;
            if (input[j] == '0') zeroes++;
        }
        if (ones > 1) sb.Append('1');
        if (zeroes > 1) sb.Append('0');
    }

    return sb.ToString();   
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(Major("101110011"));
Console.WriteLine(Major("111000111"));
```

Результат

```
111
101
```

Comment: Можете пояснить эти 2 строчки кода? Почему именно такое условие было для итераций.
for(int i=0; i<input.Length; i+=3)
for(int j=i; j<input.Length && j<i+3; j++)

Comment: @Zebren ну вам же надо было разбить текст на группы по 3 элемента? Вот i указывает на первый элемент в группе, а j испольщуется, чтобы по группе пробежать.

Comment: @Zebren дословно `пусть j перечисляет все элементы от i до i+3`, то есть перечисляем всю группу из 3 элементов, начиная с i-го элемента, потом i+1 элемент, потом i+2 элемент.

Comment: а для чего во 2-ом цикле в условии for ( int j=i; j<input.Length && j<i+3; j++ ), если достаточно написать for ( int j = i; j < i + 3; j++ )?

Comment: @Zebren это на случай, если на входе неверные данные - например если на входе `11` - 2 символа вместо трех, то есть группа не полная

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static List<string> splt(string str, int sep)
    {
        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        int lastInd = 0;
        string curStr = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i + 1) % sep == 0)
            {
                for (int j = lastInd; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    curStr += str[j];
                }
                res.Add(curStr);
                curStr = string.Empty;
                lastInd = i + 1;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static char max(string str)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        str.ToList().ForEach(e =>
        {
            try
            {
                dict[e]++;
            }
            catch
            {
                dict.Add(e, 1);
            }
        });
        KeyValuePair<char,int> max = new KeyValuePair<char, int>(' ',0);
        foreach(var item in dict)
        {
            if (item.Value > max.Value)
            {
                max = new KeyValuePair<char, int>(item.Key,item.Value);
            }
        }
        return max.Key;
    }
```

использование

```
splt("111000000111000", 5).ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(max(e)));
```

или

```
splt("111001110", 3).ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(max(e)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая весьма удобная библиотека [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ).
Если взять её и использовать метод `Batch`, то можно написать очень короткий код:

```
static string Major(string input)
{
    var result = input
        .Batch(3)
        .Select(b => b.Count(c => c == '1') > 1 ? "1" : "0");

    return string.Concat(result);
}
```

Не забываем открыть пространство имён:

```
using MoreLinq;
```

Конечно, не стоит тащить эту библиотеку в проект ради одного метода. Но если она уже используется (а в ней много вкусных расширений), то обратите внимание.

```
Console.WriteLine(Major("101110011")); // 111
Console.WriteLine(Major("111000111")); // 101
```